# Creating a new subdirectory in multiple existing directories

Tags: bash, mkdir

I am trying to figure out an elegant way to create a new subdirectory in a series of existing directories.

I have 15 already created directories called Week1 through Week15.  Within those directories, I'd like to create a new directory called "Assignments."  I'm thinking this might require a loop of some kind, but outside of that I'm a little lost.

I know I can "cd" into each directory and then "mkdir Assignment" and repeat this step for all 15 directories, but I know there must be an easier way.

Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it without a loop:

```
mkdir -p Week{1..15}/Assignments
```

Comment: Note that the `-p` option specifies to make the parent dirs as necessary, so this will work even if you haven't created Week1 - Week15 yet.

Comment: This is called [brace expansion](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-brace-expansion), in case someone was wondering.

Comment: `mkdir -p Week{01..15}/Assignments`

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways - try using this loop:

```
for i in {1..15}; do mkdir Week$i/Assignments; done
```

You could also cheat at the `Week` folders - use this:

```
for i in {1..15}; do mkdir Week$i; done
```

Just for future reference - if you need to do something similar.